# TypeError: a is null - Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('#table25').on('click', '.buyable', function () {
     var th = $(this);
     var thclass = $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[1];
     var td = $('#table25').find('td.'+thclass);
     if ($('#checkuserstatus').val() == "0") {
        $('#pleaslogin').modal('show');
        return;
     }
     var prodtitle = $('#table25title').text();
     var hex = rgbhex(td.css('background-color'));
     if (hex != '#859de6') {
        var y = '';
        var x = '';
        var xy = th.data('buyable');
        var pageurl = document.URL;
        $.ajax({
            url: '/prod_selected/',
            type: 'get',
            data: {title: prodtitle, xy: xy, x: x, y: y, pageurl: pageurl}
        }).done(function (data) {
            if (data != 'bad') {
              $('#cart').text(data);
              td.css('background-color', '#859de6');
              td.css('color', '#ffffff');
            }
        });
     }
 });
```

this is working in Chrome, but not in FireFox, I am getting:

```
TypeError: a is null
```

[image]

what am I missing? I am using the latest jquery lib

I replaced jquery.min.js with uncompressed one, now I see in this line is happenning the error. what is it? how can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: You can try and use the non-minified version of jquery to see the error with more details.

Comment: @IgalS. thanks good point to debug

Comment: @IgalS. updated the question, any ideas why?

Comment: Do you still get "a is null"? Because `a` is probably an optimized variable or parameter name. Also, do you get this error instantly or after clicking the table?

Comment: @JustusRomijn yes, still getting ``a is null``. I get this error, once I click on table

Comment: I think `var td = $('#table25').find('td.'+thclass);` is giving multiple nodes and `td.css('background-color')` is failing.